# How do I use ui-sref in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular

I'm upgrading an app from Angular 1 to Angular 2 using ngUpgrade. I do not have time to switch from ui-router to the new router in Angular 2. What do I need to do to make use of the ui-sref attribute directive in templates belonging to components written with Angular2? For what I understand ngUpgrade is only capable of converting element directives.